# Ember: this.router.refresh() throws error in ember octane

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-octane

This is the below code I am using while doing refresh the route

```
export default class MyController extend Controller {
    @service router;

    @action refresh() {
         this.router.refresh()
    }
}
```

While calling this.router.refresh() it throws like refresh function not present.

Comment: The RFC has been merged recently https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/631 and I don't think it's landed in a version yet. This might help: https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/issues/629#issuecomment-631820472

Answer (score 1):

The `RouterService` does not have a `refresh` method yet. [An RFC to add one](https://emberjs.github.io/rfcs/0631-refresh-method-for-router-service.html) was merged in October 2020 but has not been implemented yet.

This hasn't changed with Ember Octane. The `RouterService` never had a `refresh` method yet. Maybe you meant the [`refresh` method of `Route`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.23/classes/Route/methods/refresh?anchor=refresh)? This one exists both in Octane as well as before.